# Are "was/were able to" and "could" interchangeable?

Tags: meaning, grammar, word-usage, ambiguity, modal-verbs

In a grammar book, the claim was made that in the following sentences one cannot substitute "was/were able to" with "could."

> - The fire spread through the building very quickly, but everyone *was able to* escape.
> - They didn't want to come with us at first, but finally we *were able to* persuade them

However, when I searched for the term "finally could" in the *Corpus of Contemporary American English*, I found [some counter-examples](https://www.english-corpora.org/coca/x3.asp?xx=1&w11=finally&w12=could&r=). Here are two examples from COCA:

> - I told her to get in line. Did it make you feel better? It did. I *finally could* say something.
> - Then, when it ended and I *finally could* get my family back, it came at a price, like suddenly being blind.

Are these examples grammatically incorrect?

**Remark:**
I asked the same question [here](https://ell.stackexchange.com/questions/24763/could-vs-was-able-to).
It got a few answers, but unfortunately I don't find them very persuasive (my apology for those who kindly answered).

Comment: Oh, yes, this is a good one. :) -- There is a difference between the two expressions, as to meaning. All the examples you have there are grammatical, and acceptable in their contexts.

Comment: @F.E. Indeed -and I'm thoroughly looking forward to reading your answer :)

Answer (score 4):

> 1. The fire spread through the building very quickly, but everyone **was able to** escape.
> 2. They didn't want to come with us at first, but finally we **were able to** persuade them.
> 3. I told her to get in line. Did it make you feel better? It did. I finally **could** say something.
> 4. Then, when it ended and I finally **could** get my family back, it came at a price, like suddenly being blind.

All four of the examples you have there are grammatical, and they are all acceptable in their specific contexts.

***CAVEAT:*** *This post is written on the fly, off the top of my head, etc., etc., and so, be forewarned.*

There can often be a difference in meaning between the two expressions: ***"BE able to Verb"*** and ***"could".*** The context that they are in will often be a significant factor.

First, let's look at the four directly involved clauses in isolation:

1. Everyone **was able to escape.**
2. We **were able to persuade** them.
3. I (finally) **could** say something.
4. I (finally) **could** get my family back.

**1/2: "BE able to Verb":** The first two (#1, #2) could strongly imply that everyone did escape (#1), and we did persuade them (#2). If that type of strong implication is not immediately cancelled, or if the context had not already cancelled it, then that implication is then assumed to be a fact by the reader.

Though, the strength of that implicature could depend on the "Verb". For instance, for #2, it would be relatively hard to create a context where that implicature is not realized, that though we had the capability to persuade him, we chose not to. But for #1, that is not the case, as it would be easier in this case to come up with a context where that implicature is not fulfilled, e.g.:

- *I cut their ropes, thus freeing all the captives. Everyone* ***was able to escape,*** *but they just remained there in their seats. They looked like plastic mannequins. "Go, leave," I said. They gave me blank stares.*

Creating a corresponding context for #2 would be a bit trickier (if possible at all):

- *. . . We* ***were able to persuade*** *them, but we chose not too. . . .* [???]

**3/4: "could":** As for your last two (#3, #4), it seems that there isn't any implicature (or else there is only a weak one) that "I" actually did say something (#3), or that "I" did get my family back. All those two are saying is that the possibility was there: for me to say something, for me to get my family back. There isn't anything there to strongly imply whether or not I did. The context they are in will probably have to explicitly say if I actually did.

Now, let's look at those four versions in their original contexts:

> 1) The fire spread through the building very quickly, but everyone **was able to** escape.

The context makes the very, very strong implicature that everyone did escape. If everyone didn't escape, then the writer has to immediately cancel that implicature.

> 2) They didn't want to come with us at first, but finally we **were able to** persuade them.

The context makes the implicature too strong to be cancelled. That is, it is a fact that we did persuade them to come with us. But, it is still an implicature (a cancelable one) that they did end up coming with us--for it is possible that something then happened to prevent that.

> 3) I told her to get in line. Did it make you feel better? It did. I finally **could** say something.

It is the context--that I had earlier told her to get in line--that makes it a fact that not only could I say something but that I actually had said something. But a different context for that last sentence can easily show a situation where I didn't say something:

- *There was a gap in the conversation. All of her friends were temporarily occupied with paying the waitress. I finally* *could* *say something. But now, I thought better of it, and I wisely decided it best to keep my trap shut.*

> 4) Then, when it ended and I finally **could** get my family back, it came at a price, like suddenly being blind.

Here, the context has it pretty much open-ended: that is, the reader doesn't yet know if I actually did get my family back. Here's a continuation where I don't:

- *Then, when it ended and I finally* *could* *get my family back, it came at a price, like suddenly being blind. But I like seeing, like watching TV and going to the movies, and reading books, and driving my car. And anyway, my family never much noticed my absence before, and so, I turned down the devil's not so generous offer. Living alone ain't so bad, and it's got its advantages. Like full control of the TV remote.*

CAVEAT: I did this post off the top of my head. And now, maybe I'll go and do a little checking to see if I made any major goofs. . . .

Comment: Here's another example from COCA.
"As the dirty hair was cleared from the face, Michael could finally see the eyes staring back. They looked at him with a mix of emotion: fear and anger, shame and rage."
This seems to be a real counter-example for the grammar book's claim.

Comment: @ivanhoescott True, however... perception verbs appear to be an exception to the rule, because we use them with ***can*** when what we mean doesn't seem to be an active issue concerning ability or potential, but merely a passive situation. For example "I can see you"  seems to mean something more like "I see you" than "I'm able to see you" - or so the theory goes... It doesn't work like that in all languages interestingly...

Comment: @Araucaria Here's yet another example from COCA.
*Olivia could finally say with conviction,
" I'm glad we stuck it out. It was worth every agonizing minute. "*

Comment: "The context makes the very, very strong implicature..." I disagree it's the word *everyone* that tells us nobody died in the fire. Otherwise we would use a different word or expression, "many hundreds/dozens/several/precious few etc. were able to escape". Sentence No4 it is the phrase "it came at a price" that confirms that the family *did* come back. Why do you say the reader doesn't know or that it is open-ended? I can't see it, personally.

Comment: @F.E.: 'implicature'?! Poetic licence?